# Missing semicolon and syntax error in Access

Tags: sql, ms-access, syntax

I am learning SQL in class and I am confused because we have learned that semi colons aren't needed in `ACCESS`, and yet I am getting an error that I need one, and the error is highlighting my second `INSERT INTO` statement.

```
 INSERT INTO FlashDrive
 VALUES ('4001', '4', '$15')
 INSERT INTO Product
 VALUES ('C', '4001', 'FlashDrive')
```

I have even tried adding the semi-colon at the end of the SQL statement as it asks and I still get the semicolon error.

I am also getting a syntax error in this `CREATE TABLE SQL`:

```
CREATE TABLE Flash Dive{
Model SMALLINT,
Storage NUMBER,
Price SMALLINT,
PRIMARY KEY (Model),
FOREIGN KEY (Model) REFERENCES Product (Model)
}
```

The Create Table issue was answered by below. And I ended up fixing the semicolon issue by making two separate queries, instead of using one query.

Comment: '4001' (with the quotes) is not a SMALLINT, and '4' (with the quotes) is not a NUMBER. Remove the quotes. Your `CREATE TABLE` has a space between `Flash` and `Drive`, and should use `()` and not `{}` around the column definitions.

Comment: I am still getting the missing semicolon error:

INSERT INTO FlashDrive
VALUES (4001, 4, 15)
INSERT INTO Product
VALUES ('C', 4001, 'FlashDrive')

Comment: I did try that already, like this:

INSERT INTO FlashDrive(model, storage, price)
VALUES (4001, 4, 15);
INSERT INTO Product(maker, model, type)
VALUES ('C', 4001, 'FlashDrive');

And get this error:
Characters found after end of SQL statement. (Error 3142)

Comment: Figured it out.  I needed two separate operations.  I was trying to combine two insert into's into one operation.

Comment: Glad to hear that you got your issue sorted out. If you feel so inclined you can post your own answer to help future readers (and you might collect a few reputation points, too).

Comment: @JPHochbaum You should post the solutions as an answer, rather than putting the answer in your question. This will make it easier to see what the problem is vs the solution.

Answer (score 0):

As @Ken White said

> `'4001'` (with the quotes) is not a SMALLINT, and `'4'` (with the quotes) is not a NUMBER. Remove the quotes. You should use `()` and not `{}` around the column definitions. The syntax error comes from the space between `Flash Drive`. It should be `FlashDrive`.

The semi-colon error is due to the fact that operations have to be separated.